# How to use complete AngularJS file in your program?

Tags: angularjs

Up until now I was using links to minified AngularJS files in my code, but now there is a requirement because of which I have to use complete AngularJS file. I have downloaded it from the official site, and:

```
<script src="../Angular/angular.js"> </script>
<script src="../Angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="../Angular/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="../Angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="Angular/angular-loader.js"></script>
<script src="../Angular/angular-message-format.js"></script>
<script src="../Angular/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="../Angular/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="../Angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="../Angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../Angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="../Angular/angula-scenario.js"></script>
<script src="../Angular/angular-touch.js"></script>
```

and this is how I added all these files in my code, but it is not working, please let me know what is the correct way of using complete AngularJS file.

Comment: can you create codepen for that? so i can see what is problem.

Comment: `is not working` is not a proper problem description. Look in your console and provide basic debugging information. It's pretty obvious that one file path shown is different than the others. The network tab of browser dev tools should also show where problems are

Comment: http://codepen.io/priyanshi/pen/oXKdKO?editors=100       this is the link to the code pen.   earlier i was using links but now i have downloaded and imported angularjs files, but my whole application is not working properly some functionalities are missing, so what is the way of using files in place of links

Answer (score 0):

Your path for angular-loader is different from the rest of your paths. I'm not sure if any of them are correct. I'd recommend starting the Chrome developer tools and then going to the Network tab to see if all of your resources are loading correctly.

Comment: oops!!  the path is same , i typed wrong.   sry for that.   i corrected it, yes i checked all my files are loading correctly.  but my application's complete functionality is not working  so how should i use complete angularjs file in place of links to minified versions . Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your codepen it appears that you are reloading the Angular libraries later in your HTML. That is probably causing Angular to reinstantiate and therefore destroying whatever you've done in your code in between. Try deleting or commenting out the lines where you load Angular from cloudflare.

Comment: yeah i have commented out that line. And those angularjs files are loading i have checked but i dont't know what is the issue because my app's views are not changing . so may be i am loading these files in wrong way....     do u have any idea how should i load these non minified angularjs files

Comment: Can you update your codepen and add your js to it as well?